# How do I set the bulletpoints towards the top of text?

Tags: html, css

How do I set the bulletpoints towards the top of text? Here's my code example below...

```css
.article-bulletpnts li::marker {
    font-size: 8px; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="article-bulletpnts">
        <li>
            European minnow priapumfish mosshead warbonnet shrimpfish 
            bigscale.Cutlassfish porbeagle shark ricefish walking catfish
        </li>
        <li>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do            
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
            enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Font-size of 12px centers it better. What do you mean towards the top?

Comment: You could put your text as a subscript: `<li> <sub>Your text here</sub> </li>` .

Comment: I'm trying to put each bullet point near the top of the text they are adjacent to

Comment: M-Coder your tip worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for you issue is because you are only targeting the ::marker and making the ::marker 8px but your font is the default size. If you are going to change the size of the marker then you should also match the font size of the `li` to it.

```
li {
  font-size: 8px;
}
li::marker {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

For Example

```css
ul.article-bulletpnts li::marker {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="article-bulletpnts">
        <li>
            European minnow priapumfish mosshead warbonnet shrimpfish 
            bigscale.Cutlassfish porbeagle shark ricefish walking catfish
        </li>
        <li>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do            
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
            enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
        </li>
</ul>
```